# MySql Driver Class Autoloading

Tags: java, mysql, maven, pom.xml

**Configuration**

**jdk version** : 1.8.0_60-b27

**project** : maven jsp project

**Mysql connector** : mysql-connector-java-5.1.38 (Copied to Tomcat's lib)

**Pom.xml**

```
 <!--MySql Connector/J Dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Code Causing Error** :

```
try(Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","root","")){
            connection=con;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

**Error log**

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at util.DBConnectivity.getDBConnection(DBConnectivity.java:16)
    at controller.MyController.doGet(MyController.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried both of the `scopes` [`provided` and `compile`] in pom.xml but no change in the output!!!

Tried hundred times but can't figure out why project is not able to find the driver????

Comment: With `provided` it isn't going to work anyway it needs to be part of your application. When adding it to the tomcat lib directory you would need to restart tomcat else it won't work either (and then it should work with `provided`).

Comment: @M.Deinum - I did restart the tomcat with every change in the scope. But no change in output!!!!!!!

Comment: Remove the scope (default is `compile`) remove the lib from the tomcat lib dir and make sure it is in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Redeploy.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Tried it but no use!!!. I put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar` downloaded from `dev.mysql.com` to `WEB-INF/lib` but no use!!

Comment: Ehrm.. Why are you doing that yourself? You are using maven so use maven to build the war and dependencies. Don't mess with dependencies manually as those won't be included.

Comment: @M.Deinum Tried that way too!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99917/discussion-between-mr-arjun-and-m-deinum).

Comment: seems that http://stackoverflow.com/a/28900618/3215527 answers your question.

Comment: Probably a stupid q but just to check, is the dependency is definitely in the `<dependencies>` section of a `pom.xml` that is being read as part of the build (and not for example only listed in the `<dependencyManagement>` section instead?)

Comment: Which version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: You say, you copied to * Copied to Tomcat's lib*. Where is that? Exactly.

Comment: @jah that means my container provides this jar to application at run time, as i have put a copy of `driver jar` in the `CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory. and the versions I have tested with are tomcat `8.0.28` and most recent version of tomcat 8 i.e. `tomcat 8.0.3`

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is just these two steps, and not more:

1. **Include your dependency properly**:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.38</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Notice that scope is not configures, so by default it will be `compile`, which will make it available at runtime too.

The combination of manually copying this file to `WEB-INF\lib` then redeploy with `scope=provided` will *not* work because the folder will get recreated. In case you would like to make this jar available only at runtime, you need to place it to `Tomcat\lib`.

2. **You need to manually load the driver** before you attempt to connect anywhere. Make sure you do this before using `DriverManager`.

   `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: I have the `mysql-connector-java` jar file to Tomcat's lib directory so scope is `privided`. And your second point kindly read the driver autoloading part from `oracle documentation` here http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html#rrefjdbc4_0summary

Comment: I can only tell you that what Gergely Bacso wrote you actually stands, and is a correct way of manually obtaining the java.sql.Connection. Your application absolutely doesn't need mysql connection driver in a tomcat lib folder and maven doesn't need any specific scope in your mysql dependency: I know that for a fact cause I wrote this exact code myself 4 weeks ago, and everything worked as it is expected to work. Also, piece of advice: Tend to make your applications self-sufficient if you can, do not rely them on specific server configurations (like changing the contents of tomcat lib folder).

Answer (score -1):

you are not getting the connection from a datasource hence you are not using the mysql driver in the tomcat lib.

Using DriverManager you need to load the jdbc library yourself using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` and by removing the `provided` entry for it in the `pom.xml` or... use a datasource :)

Comment: When using JDBC4 that isn't needed anymore, drivers register themselves. That line is for non JDBC4 drivers.